# Just trying to call a function of a library

Tags: c++, ogg-theora

I have a code like this below in `/root_project/main.cpp`:

```
#include "theoraplayer/TheoraVideoClip.h"

unsigned int tex_id;
TheoraVideoManager* mgr;
TheoraVideoClip* clip;
std::string window_name="glut_player";
bool started=1;
int window_w=800,window_h=600;

void draw()
{
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,tex_id);

    TheoraVideoFrame* f=clip->getNextFrame();   //this gives an error!!!
    if (f)
    {
```

and the `TheoraVideoClip.h` file is in `/root_project/include/theoraplayer/`.

Inside of `TheoraVideoClip.h` there is this:

```
TheoraVideoFrame* getNextFrame();
```

And when I try to compile using `g++ -o app main.cpp -lGL -lglut -lGLU`
 I'm gettin this error:

> main.cpp:(.text+0xac2): undefined reference to
>   `TheoraVideoClip::getNextFrame()'

Anyone knows Why?

Ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to link to `libtheoraplayer`.

Comment: where? in the command to compile? I did 'g++ -o app main.cpp -lGL -lglut -lGLU -libtheoraplayer' but it says '/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -libtheoraplayer'.

Comment: @tirengarfio : That should be `-ltheoraplayer`, and since you appear to have the library in a non-default location you'll probably need to use `-L` to specify that location as well .

Comment: i found this link http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/24862/ and now I'm writing this: g++ -o app main.cpp -lGL -lglut -lGLU -ltheora -ltheoradec but the error is the same..

Comment: @tirengarfio : You're still missing the `-L` to tell the linker where to find the libraries. (I'm assuming you actually _built_ the library, rather than just having the source...)

Comment: I think the libraries are been founded, because if i write -ltheorafoobar it says it couldn't find that library..

Comment: Now, I understand... I think I have to compile the libraries and then compile linking to the compiled libraries..

Comment: @tirengarfio : Indeed. Sorry, I assumed you had built the library already, or I would have been more specific. :-]